# Me salta el siguiente error expected an idented block

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

soy algo nuevo en esto de la programación, he visto varios codigos, pero no logro el punto que quiero llegar, quiero poner que se yo mis pasatiempos, un reproductor de musica y una foto de fondo. Pero esto me salta el error del titulo.

```
class App:

def __init__(self, master):
    frame = tk.Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.button = tk.Button(frame, text='play', command=self.play_sound)
    self.button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    self.button2 = tk.Button(frame, text='stop', command=self.stop_sound)
    self.button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


def ayuda(self):#funcion para que aparezca la ayuda
    root=Toplevel(bg="BLUE")#crea una ventana con fondo celeste    
    root.minsize(300,0)# tamaño de ventana
    root.resizable(width=NO,height=NO)# no se hace mas pequña
    root.title("About")#titulo
    instruccion=Message(root,text="Soy Róger ")
    # lo anterior es el mensaje que se imprime 
    instruccion.place(x=0,y=0)#lugar del mensaje

def play_sound(self):
        PlaySound('Sound.wav', SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC)

def stop_sound(self):
        PlaySound(None, SND_FILENAME)

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Creo que todos los `def` deben estar indentados respecto del `Class`. Así como está, la clase App no tiene nada

Comment: Si no escribiste mal el código aquí, el error está en la línea 2, y es por que necesitas escribir con espacios para algo esté dentro de `class`, ósea así `[espacio][espacio]def __init__:` y no así `def __init__:`

Answer (score 1):

Claro te salta porque los def tienen que estar identados con la class osea cuando tenemos una aplicacion en python apretamos "TAB" para decir que un comando va dentro de otro en el caso de una funcion

```
def funcion()
>   Esto va a dentro de la funcion

class Name:
>   Esto va dentro de la clase

class Name:
    #esta funcion esta dentro de la clase
    def funcion():
        #esta linea va dentro de la funcion
```

pon atencion a eso aqui te lo paso corregido

```
class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text='play', command=self.play_sound)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(frame, text='stop', command=self.stop_sound)
        self.button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


    def ayuda(self):#funcion para que aparezca la ayuda
        root=Toplevel(bg="BLUE")#crea una ventana con fondo celeste    
        root.minsize(300,0)# tamaño de ventana
        root.resizable(width=NO,height=NO)# no se hace mas pequña
        root.title("About")#titulo
        instruccion=Message(root,text="Soy Róger ")
        # lo anterior es el mensaje que se imprime 
        instruccion.place(x=0,y=0)#lugar del mensaje

    def play_sound(self):
        PlaySound('Sound.wav', SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC)

    def stop_sound(self):
        PlaySound(None, SND_FILENAME)

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```